# How to document with Doxygen a file include

Tags: c, doxygen

I have some includes in the source code where I want to add some "to do".

For example:

```
/** \todo Review. */
#include "anyfile.h"

/** todo Another to do. */
#define ANY_MACRO 1
```

The problem is that the first "to do" is inserted in the macro definition and not in the include, as followed:

```
-----------------------------------
**Todo List**

Global **ANY_MACRO**

Review.

Another to do.

-----------------------------------
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Following the [online doc](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html):

> Let's repeat that, because it is often overlooked: to document global objects (functions, typedefs, enum, macros, etc), you must document the file in which they are defined.

Then I handle your problem in the following manner: I must have a `\file` comment in both files, and above the include line, I mention that the todo part refers to the included file.

In other words, I write this in my source file afile.c:

```
/** \file anyfile.h
 *  \todo Review
 */
#include "anyfile.h"

/** \file afile.c
 *  \brief Some code
 */

/** \todo wait, a todo !*/
#define A_MACRO

int main()
{}
```

In the included file, I write a short comment about the file itself:

```
/** \file anyfile.h 
 *  Very interesting header
 */

#define B_MACRO
```

As output, the todo comment is placed in the doc page of the included file. The awkward part according to me is that I have to put the block `/** \file afile.c */` after the include line, otherwise it doesn't work.